# Why doesn't rand work with AbstractFloat?

Tags: julia

In Julia 0.4.0, when I try

```
rand(AbstractFloat, 1)
```

The following error is obtained:

```
ERROR: MethodError: `rand` has no method matching rand(::MersenneTwister,
::Type{AbstractFloat})
```

Is there a reason behind the fact that I must explicitly say `Float32` or `Float64` for `rand` to work? Or is it just that, as the language is relatively new, a relevant method has yet to be defined in the Base?

Comment: Julia don't know which type you prefer among `BigFloat`, `Float16`, `Float32` and `Float64`.

Comment: But for example `one(AbstractFloat)` gives either a  `Float32` or `Float64` object depending on the system. Shouldn't `rand` have the same behaviour?

Comment: Good case, in my opinion, it's better for Julia to behave the same in alike situations, like the above.

Comment: Since `rand(Float64)` does not actually cover the whole range of `Float64` values, but the [0,1) interval unlike the `Int` family, it seems reasonable to define this as an Abstract behavior and extend to `AbstractFloat`. Good point @Taiki

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`one` is different from `rand`. 
when using `one(AbstractFloat)`, all the outputs are the "same":

```
julia> one(Float64)
1.0

julia> one(Float32)
1.0f0

julia> 1.0 == 1.0f0
true
```

this is not true when using `rand`:

```
julia> rand(srand(1), Float64)
0.23603334566204692

julia> rand(srand(1), Float32)
0.5479944f0

julia> rand(srand(1), Float32) == rand(srand(1), Float64)
false
```

this means if `rand` would behave like `one`, one might get two different results with the same seed on two different machines(e.g. one is x86, another is x64). take a look at the code in [random.jl](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/f8a4340548e7d6be31fede13cdc4e0f5f434f33f/base/random.jl#L232):

> @inline rand{T<:Union{Bool, Int8, UInt8, Int16, UInt16, Int32, UInt32}}(r::MersenneTwister, ::Type{T}) = rand_ui52_raw(r) % T

both `rand(Signed)`&`rand(Unsigned)` are illegal too.

Comment: Very reasonable :) Thanks.